# tool for monitoring the windows messages used by an external application

Tags: winapi, monitoring, windows-messages

i am looking a tool for monitoring the windows messages fired by an external application in real-time.

some time ago i used winsight32 (tool that ships with Delphi), but is very memory expensive and freeze my laptop.

[image]
<sub>(source: [blong.com](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/DCon99/FAQs/Image23.gif))</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Winspector is probably what you want.  Not only you can look at all the messages, but also at all windows flags.

Answer (score 0):

Does [API Monitor](http://www.rohitab.com/apimonitor) do what you need?

Alternately, if you have Visual Studio installed (full, not express), there is a sample called Spy++ which might do what you want.

Comment: If I recall correctly Spy++ is also provided for free in the Platform SDK.